# Ldap Authentication retrieves no information in php

Tags: php, ldap

I have successfully authenticated against ldap in php, but I'm not able to retrieve information during search. This Ad authentication works fine in .net application but in php I have not received any information during search.

```
    $search_filter = "(sAMAccountName=*xyz*)" ; 
    $attributes = array("memberof","givenname");
    $ldap = ldap_connect($server);

    if($ldap) 
        echo "successful";  

    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3); // generally needed with AD.
    //ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 2.4);
    ldap_set_option($ldap, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);

    $ldapbind  = ldap_bind($ldap,$username,$password); 

    if ($ldapbind) {
        echo "<br> LDAP Connect successful...";
    } else {
        echo "<br>LDAP Connect failed...";      
    }

    $search = ldap_search($ldap, $base_dn, $search_filter);
    $data = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $search);
```

Comment: Okay, first you haven't actually asked a question and second we need some relevant code.

Comment: any suggestion where i'm doing wrong.

Comment: What is your `$base_dn` set to? Directly following your search, put in a `var_dump(ldap_error($ldap));`. What does that output?